# Unable to Run GraphFrames with PySpark on Windows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, graphframes

I am trying to run PySpark on Windows with [GraphFrames](http://graphframes.github.io/quick-start.html).

The GraphFrames QuickStart Guide mentions following -

> If you have GraphFrames available as a JAR graphframes.jar, you can make GraphFrames available by passing the JAR to the pyspark shell script as follows:

```
$ ./bin/pyspark --master local[4] --py-files graphframes.jar --jars graphframes.jar
```

Is there a similar command (like `--py-files`) to include the *.jar* distribution in Windows?

I tried using **NotebookApp.file_to_run** = "graphframes-0.2.0-spark1.5-s_2.10.jar", but that did not work.
Is there some other way to run GraphFrames with PySpark on Windows? TIA.

What I run in command line to start PySpark:

```
ipython notebook %SPARK_HOME%/bin/pyspark
```

Final Command I tried to run GraphFrames:

```
ipython notebook %SPARK_HOME%/bin/pyspark NotebookApp.file_to_run=graphframes-0.2.0-spark1.5-s_2.10.jar
```